# Xamarin custom schedular view?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

So I am creating an app in Xamarin forms. I am an experienced .net developer but my Xamarin forms knowledge is still in the early stages.

I want to create a new custom control (Scheduler / Timeline control) that looks like the following picture:
[image: Scheduler]

My first idea was to start from controls already existing in Xamarin forms like Grid,...
But now I am thinking, if it is maybe better to start from Android and IOS controls instead?

**Is there somebody who has experience in making custom controls like this for Xamarin Forms, and can you point me in the right direction?**

Comment: Probably not a suitable question here. Some links might help: https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/scheduler/monthview, 
https://www.infragistics.com/products/xamarin/scheduling/schedule

Comment: @Shaw these links are not really helping, because the controls they give are calendars and don't look like this. And second, they don't show you the source code so I cannot figure out how they do it...

Comment: @kevingoos There are no free out of the box component for your view, Avaiable ones are from syncfusion , telrik etc. You need to avail their free community lience to use their component. There is documentation available in their site https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/scheduler/weekview?_ga=2.21299901.782375520.1620114626-491749628.1619541874

Comment: Basically you need to install syncfusion nuget and avail their free licence in order to use their out of the box sheduler component

Comment: More info : https://github.com/SyncfusionExamples/xamarin-forms-appointment-scheduler

Comment: @Anand k I understand that, but this doesn't take a way that it doesn't have the control that I am looking for. I think I need to make my own custom control, to get something that looks like the image. But the question is where do I start for that? Just create something using standard Xamarin.Forms controls? Or is there another way to do it?

Comment: @kevingoos well, if you are planning to create your own control, Collectionview and grid will be the path I think.